# Como remover elementos clonados javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como remover apenas o ultimo node clonado?

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function clonar() {
var linha = document.getElementById("linha");
var clone = linha.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("saida").appendChild(clone);  
}
```

```css
button {width:50px}
.quadrado {
background:black;
height:50px;
width:50px;
margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="linha"><div class="quadrado"></div></div>
<div id="saida"></div>
<button id="add">ADD</button><br>
<button id="del">DEL</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
document.querySelector('#saida #linha:last-child').remove();
```